# SQL query that returns a set

Tags: sql

I have a following table

```
socket_id | event_type | response
----------+------------+---------
    2     |      2     |  404
----------+------------+---------
    2     |      4     |  200
----------+------------+---------
    2     |      2     |  500
----------+------------+---------
    3     |      2     |  400
----------+------------+---------
    2     |      3     |  404
----------+------------+---------
```

I need an SQL query that returns a set of all sockets with number of different event types registered by each of them, ordered by socket_id ASC

So far I wrote this query by it doesn't return different event_types for same socket_id.

```
  SELECT socket_id,
     SUM(CASE WHEN event_type >= 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) types
     FROM Events
     GROUP BY socket_id;
```

Comment: Edit the question add your desired result with appropriate DBMS tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As if you mean this :

```
  SELECT socket_id,
         count(distinct event_type) as types
    FROM Events
   GROUP BY socket_id
   ORDER BY socket_id;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your description suggests me :

```
SELECT socket_id, COUNT(event_type) AS types
FROM Events
GROUP BY socket_id
ORDER BY socket_id;
```

If you want unique `event_type` count then use `DISTINCT` inside `COUNT()`.